# Combine Get-ADGroup and Get-ADUser Results

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a single output of the following two commands.  In my head I think of SQL joins on the DN's here but I'm at a loss of what to do to combine these.

I would like to get the "Name" from Get-ADGroup for column A and the "Name" for Get-ADUser for column B.  In SQL I could do this by joining on ManagedBy from Get-ADGroup and DistinguishedName from Get-ADUser.  I hope that was clear enough...

**Query 1**

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -Properties ManagedBy | Select Name,ManagedBy
```

**Result 1**

*Accounts-SG               CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=Accounting,OU=Corp,OU=Corporate,OU=Bozeman,OU=Montana,OU=US,OU=NA,DC=ad,DC=yourdomain,DC=com*

---

**Query 2**

```
Get-ADUser -identity John.Doe | select Name, DistinguishedName
```

**Result 2**

*John Doe               CN=John Doe,OU=Users,OU=Accounting,OU=Corp,OU=Corporate,OU=Bozeman,OU=Montana,OU=US,OU=NA,DC=ad,DC=yourdomain,DC=com*

---

**Desired Result (Get-ADGroup Name + Get-ADUser Name**

*Accounts-SG               John Doe*

Please help,
-Rob

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this problem before, and there isn't a super nice way built in. In the past, I've used this script, [Merge-Csv.ps1](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/An_Advanced_Cmdlet_to_Merge_Csv_Files_in_PowerShell), and it's worked well for me.

However, maybe you could use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to swap out the `DistinguishedName` for their `Name`?

So something like:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -Properties ManagedBy | Select Name, @{Name="ManagedByName";Expression={Get-AdUser -Identity "$_" | Select -Expand Name}}
```